# How do you get this effect in latex? Matrix boxed (Without nicematrix pack)

Tags: nicematrix

I have a problem with these matrices, how do I code the matrices to look like the picture? Without
additional packs. I have that packs already: amsmath,mathtools.  [image]

Comment: 1) If you load `mathtools`, needless to load `amsth`. It is already loaded by mathtools; 2) The simplest  to the matrices uses the `blkarray`  package.

Comment: You can do this also with `nicematrix` package pretty easily. Well, you probably know that since you tagged it.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600997/161015